# MDX Calculated member fixed

Tags: ssas, mdx, member

i want to ask, if there is some function in MDX language, which returns me a same value in any case..

I created a calculated member, that's indicate how much value was sold on last year. It's work fine. But if I in slicer or filter exclude year value of the last year, i get nothing. Is there any function, that calculate a value with no filter?

For example, I need function like calculate in DAX in power pivot.

Thanks

Edit:

MDX calculated member for [Mat value]:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[MAT value]
 AS SUM([03 Datumy].[MAT].&[MAT],[Measures].[Sales value]), 
FORMAT_STRING = "#,##0.00;-#,##0.00", 
VISIBLE = 1 ,  DISPLAY_FOLDER = 'Sales value' ,  ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = '04 Hodnoty'  ;
```

MDX calculated member for [Mat-1 value]:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[MAT-1 value]
 AS SUM([03 Datumy].[MAT].&[MAT-1],[Measures].[Sales value]), 
FORMAT_STRING = "#,##0.00;-#,##0.00", 
VISIBLE = 1 ,  DISPLAY_FOLDER = 'Sales value' ,  ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = '04 Hodnoty'  ;
```

[mat2014 http://www.attanon.eu/mat2014.PNG](http://www.attanon.eu/mat2014.PNG)[mat2013 http://www.attanon.eu/mat2013.PNG](http://www.attanon.eu/mat2013.PNG)
[filters http://www.attanon.eu/filters.PNG](http://www.attanon.eu/filters.PNG)[all http://www.attanon.eu/allmat.PNG](http://www.attanon.eu/allmat.PNG)

Edit2:

MAT and MAT-1 is based on column with this value. I have dimension like this:
[dimension http://www.attanon.eu/dimension.PNG](http://www.attanon.eu/dimension.PNG)

And data looks that:
[datumy http://www.attanon.eu/datumy.PNG](http://www.attanon.eu/datumy.PNG)

Relationship in [03 Datumy]:

[relations http://www.attanon.eu/relations.PNG](http://www.attanon.eu/relations.PNG)

The mat is calculated in SQL server. Because, i don't have much time to calculate the hiearchy in cube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(discussion updates were removed as lack of necessity)

**UPDATE to fix an issue:**

Since your calculation, that determines months belonging to certain month, based on SQL, you can filter-out Date hierarchy by rewriting MAT-measures with adding `[03 Datumy].[Year].[All]`:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[MAT value]
 AS ([03 Datumy].[MAT].&[MAT],[03 Datumy].[Year].[All],[Measures].[Sales value]), 
FORMAT_STRING = "#,##0.00;-#,##0.00", 
VISIBLE = 1 ,  DISPLAY_FOLDER = 'Sales value' ,  ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = '04 Hodnoty'  ;
```

and the same for next one:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[MAT-1 value]
 AS ([03 Datumy].[MAT].&[MAT-1],[03 Datumy].[Year].[All],[Measures].[Sales value]), 
FORMAT_STRING = "#,##0.00;-#,##0.00", 
VISIBLE = 1 ,  DISPLAY_FOLDER = 'Sales value' ,  ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = '04 Hodnoty'  ;
```

Actually, it's an equivalent of old SSAS-2000 function `.Ignore`.

Comment: I need to use this in ms excel. Where it doesn't work.. If i set filter or slicer, the value doesn't show..

Comment: @JAttanonRadar, My sample still works in Excel (updated part of answer). Could you please update your post with an image or text of MDX statement, captured to see real query, created by Excel?

Comment: @JAttanonRadar, I believe, [03 Datumy].[MAT] hierarchy is set of rules to calculate any measure's specific periods (last year, YTD, MTD etc.). Could you please add &[MAT-1] and &[MAT] calculations too? (to see, which hierarchies are used here and why doesn't this work with simple filter)

Comment: It's no calculations. It's base on column in table.

Comment: @JAttanonRadar, got it. I've updated my answer with the calculation.

Comment: Sum function can't use more then 2 parameters. Maybe create a tuple with the time dimension. A sum values with that.. Something like this SUM(([03 Datumy].[MAT].&[MAT-1],[Year].[Year].[All]),[Measures].[Sales value]). But it isn't working.

Comment: Sorry, sure thing, tuple (03 Datumy, Year, Measure). I've just copy-pasted and forget to delete SUM! Answer was updated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68823/discussion-between-alex-peshik-and-jattanonradar).